# Tailwind classes that I change the color value of the Laravel component do not work

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

This is my component in Laravel:

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-8 h-8 text-$color-500 bg-$color-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-$color-500 dark:text-$color-200"]) }}>
                <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor"
                     viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    <path d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5Zm3.707 8.207-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 0l-2-2a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414L9 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 1.414Z"/>
                </svg>
                <span class="sr-only">Check icon</span>
            </div>
```

And I use it in view like this:
<x-toasts.toast color="amber">{{session('deleted')}}</x-toasts.toast>

But when I use some colors like red, it works, and I have tested methods such as deleting the compiled views and even changing them using javascript, but it still didn't work, but when I want, for example, from the same class I use it completely without manipulating the color variable. The colors work perfectly and the class is applied. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names in definitions, like:

  ```html
  <x-toasts.toast color="bg-amber-100 text-amber-500 dark:bg-amber-500 dark:text-amber-200">
  ```

  ```php
  <div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-8 h-8 $color"]) }}>
  ```
- Having a map of colors, like:

  ```php
  @php
  $colors = [
    'amber' => 'bg-amber-100 text-amber-500 dark:bg-amber-500 dark:text-amber-200',
    'red' => 'bg-red-100 text-red-500 dark:bg-red-500 dark:text-red-200',
    // …
  ];
  @endphp
  <div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-8 h-8 $colors[$color]"]) }}>
  ```
- [Safelisting the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) that may be used, like:

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    // …
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^bg-(amber|red|…)-100$/ },
      { pattern: /^text-(amber|red|…)-500$/ },
      {
        pattern: /^bg-(amber|red|…)-500$/,
        variants: ['dark'],
      },
      {
        pattern: /^text-(amber|red|…)-200$/,
        variants: ['dark'],
      },
    ],
    // ...
  }
  ```